# Drawer Navigator in React Navigation doesn't work when app has cache & user data

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, drawer

I'm having a problem with the drawer navigation in my React Native app built with React Navigation.

The drawer is working properly the first time the app is opened - the user can swipe/tap to open and close it as expected. However, once the app is closed and reopened, the drawer stops functioning correctly.

When the app is reloaded, tapping the drawer button no longer opens the drawer menu, no matter how many times it is pressed. The drawer navigation becomes non-responsive after an app restart. But if I clear the app cache and data from the device settings, the drawer functionality is restored and starts working correctly again.

Man, I'm really struggling with this drawer issue. It's for a school project and I've been trying to fix it for ages. No matter what I do, the drawer just stops working whenever I close the app. Really need to get this finished but I'm running out of ideas.

This is my App.JS

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from "./FirebaseConfig";
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";

import { icons, images } from "./src/constants";

// Screens
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import CrearOrdenScreen from "./src/screens/CrearOrdenScreen";
import OrdenesAllScreen from "./src/screens/ordenes/[slug]";
import OrdenScreen from "./src/screens/orden/[id]";
import BusquedaScreen from "./src/screens/search/[slug]";
import ScanScreen from "./src/screens/ScanScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/LoginScreen";
import CerrarSesionScreen from "./src/screens/CerrarScreen";
import EmpleadosScreen from "./src/screens/EmpleadosScreen";
import { ScreenHeaderBtn } from "./src/components";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function CustomDrawerContent({ navigation, state }) {
  const getCurrentRouteName = () => {
    const route = state.routes[state.index];
    return route.name;
  };

  const isRouteFocused = (routeName) => {
    return getCurrentRouteName() === routeName;
  };

  const handleDrawerItemPress = (routeName) => {
    navigation.navigate(routeName);
    navigation.closeDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.drawerContainer}>
      <View style={{ marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: 15 }}>
        <ScreenHeaderBtn
          dimension={35}
          iconUrl={icons.menu}
          handlePress={() => {
            navigation.toggleDrawer();
          }}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.drawerHeader}>
        <Image source={images.profile} style={styles.drawerHeader} />
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          styles.drawerItem,
          isRouteFocused("Home") && styles.drawerItemFocused,
        ]}
        onPress={() => handleDrawerItemPress("Home")}
      >
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.drawerItemText,
            isRouteFocused("Home") && styles.drawerItemTextFocused,
          ]}
        >
          Inicio
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          styles.drawerItem,
          isRouteFocused("CrearOrden") && styles.drawerItemFocused,
        ]}
        onPress={() => handleDrawerItemPress("CrearOrden")}
      >
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.drawerItemText,
            isRouteFocused("CrearOrden") && styles.drawerItemTextFocused,
          ]}
        >
          Crear Orden
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          styles.drawerItem,
          isRouteFocused("Escanear") && styles.drawerItemFocused,
        ]}
        onPress={() => handleDrawerItemPress("Escanear")}
      >
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.drawerItemText,
            isRouteFocused("Escanear") && styles.drawerItemTextFocused,
          ]}
        >
          Escanear
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          styles.drawerItem,
          isRouteFocused("VerEmpleados") && styles.drawerItemFocused,
        ]}
        onPress={() => handleDrawerItemPress("VerEmpleados")}
      >
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.drawerItemText,
            isRouteFocused("VerEmpleados") && styles.drawerItemTextFocused,
          ]}
        >
          Ver Empleados
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          styles.drawerItem,
          isRouteFocused("CerrarSesion") && styles.drawerItemFocused,
        ]}
        onPress={() => handleDrawerItemPress("CerrarSesion")}
      >
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.drawerItemText,
            isRouteFocused("CerrarSesion") && styles.drawerItemTextFocused,
          ]}
        >
          Cerrar Sesión
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
function App() {
  const auth = FIREBASE_AUTH;
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setIsLoggedIn(!!user);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
        drawerStyle={styles.drawer}
        screenOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "#000",
          activeBackgroundColor: "#eee",
          itemStyle: styles.drawerItem,
          labelStyle: styles.drawerItemText,
          unmountOnBlur: true,
          swipeEnabled: false,
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="CrearOrden" component={CrearOrdenScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Orden" component={OrdenScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Ordenes" component={OrdenesAllScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Busqueda" component={BusquedaScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Escanear" component={ScanScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="VerEmpleados" component={EmpleadosScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="CerrarSesion" component={CerrarSesionScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  drawerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
    marginBottom: 10,
    objectFit: "fill",
    alignSelf: "center",
    borderRadius: 100,
  },
  logo: {
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
  },
  drawerItem: {
    paddingVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "#ccc",
  },
  drawerItemText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#333",
  },
  drawerItemFocused: {
    backgroundColor: "#e6f3ff",
  },
  drawerItemTextFocused: {
    color: "#000", 
  },
});

export default App;
```

I attempted to reset the drawer state on app resume/reload by adding a drawerInitialized state variable and conditionally recreating the drawer navigator when it's false.

This was done to force a reset on app focus by checking the state and rerendering the navigator component.

I also added an effect to listen for auth state changes and navigation focus events. Inside this effect, I tried resetting the drawerInitialized state on focus in addition to checking auth.